# Does .net register a new exception handler every time a try block is opened?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

Just reading about first and second chance exceptions. And that a when debugging the debugger gets the first chance exception before the program does. That in mind how does attaching the exception handler work. Is it a case that every time a try block is opened another exception handler is attached?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that .net doesn't install a new structured exception handler for each try statement. The performance of `try...` is *much* too good for that. A logical place to install one might be when passing from native to managed code.

Comment: Exception filter lookup is table based in .NET, like it is in 64-bit native code.  The first chance notification is a pure debugger implementation detail, supported by the native Windows debugger support.  Check out the SDK docs for WaitForDebugEvent().

Answer (score 3):

Here is I found the great article by [Junfeng Zhang's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/): ["From Unhandled Exception to Debugger Attach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2007/11/19/from-unhandled-exception-to-debugger-attach.aspx)

This is called Postmortem debugging settings, you can setup postmortem debugger your self in the Windows System Registry, when Visual Studio installed the registry key `\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug` contains:

`"C:\WINNT\system32\vsjitdebugger.exe" -p %ld -e %ld`

So Visual Studio JIT debugger is defined as default postmortem debugger.

Just key points: (for fulld details see article)

> Windows can handle user-mode errors in a variety of ways. The
>   following sequence shows the precedence used for error handling:
>
> 1. If a user-mode debugger is currently attached to the faulting process, all errors will cause the target to break into this debugger.
> 2. If no user-mode debugger is attached and the executing code has its own exception handling routines (for example, try - except), this
>      exception handling routine will attempt to deal with the error.
> 3. If no user-mode debugger is attached, and Windows has an open kernel-debugging connection, and the error is a breakpoint interrupt,
>      Windows will attempt to contact the kernel debugger.

Answer (score 0):

(corrected) From a performance standpoint, using try/catch has a small hit over 2 billion iterations when run in release mode.

```
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        var cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                cnt++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);

        // takes 00:00:06.25
```

and

```
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        var cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            cnt++;
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);

        // takes 00:00:00.90
```

Comment: Be carefull with this measurement. There is a huge performance difference when running in release mode without a debugger attached! (no try/catch takes less then 1 second where with try catch takes more then 5 seconds!)

Comment: OK, I stand corrected, thanks for that @Polity!  A quick test does show 2 billion iterations chalk up 5 seconds with try/catch vs 1 second without.  Still, it's amazingly fast considering!